# Sum table values based on grouping

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
        <td class="value">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat2">cat2</td>
        <td class="value">356</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
        <td class="value">486</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need a way to add/sum all values grouped by category, ie: add/sum all values in `cat1`, then add/sum all values in `cat2`. For each group I will do something with the total.

So I was hoping for something like:

```
for each unique category:
    sum values in category
    do something with this category total
```

For `cat1` the total would be **123 + 486**. `Cat2` would just be **356**. And so on if there were more categories.

I would prefer a purely javascript solution, but JQuery will do if that's not possible.

Comment: what do you mean by "add". Add to what? What is the desired result?

Comment: Question edited for clarity. Hope that makes sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using only javascript

```
//grab data
var allTR = document.getElementsByTagName('TR');

var result = {};

//cycle table rows
for(var i=0;i<allTR.length;i+2){
    //read class and value object data
    var class = allTR[i].getAttribute('class');
    var value = allTR[i+1].innerText;

    //check if exists and add, or just add
    if(result[class])
       result[class] += parseInt(value);
    else
       result[class] = parseInt(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you do a repeat of each `td:first-child` (The category cell).

Create a `total` object. You can check if the category is exist in it for each cell. If so, add current value to the stored value. If not, insert new property to it.

Like this:

```js
var total = {};

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child'), function(td) {
  var cat = td.getAttribute('class'),
      val = parseInt(td.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
  
  if (total[cat]) {
    total[cat] += val;  
  }
  else {
    total[cat] = val;  
  }
});

console.log(total);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
    <td class="value">123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat2">cat2</td>
    <td class="value">356</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
    <td class="value">486</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  `getElementsByTagName("td");`  to get all the `<td>` collection and then you need to loop through them to fetch their `innerText` property which later can be summed up to get the summation.

**Here is the working Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/ftordw4L/1/

**HTML**

```
<table id="tbl1">
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
        <td class="value">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat2">cat2</td>
        <td class="value">356</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
        <td class="value">486</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="total"><b>Total</b></td>
        <td class="totalValue"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var tds=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var total=0;


for (var i = 0; i<tds.length; i++) {

  if (tds[i].className == "value") {
    if(total==0) {
        total = parseInt(tds[i].innerText);
    } else {
        total = total + parseInt(tds[i].innerText);
    }
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName('totalValue')[0].innerHTML = total;
```

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution with jQuery :) if you are interested. it's pretty straightforward

```js
var sumCat1 = 0;
var sumCat2 = 0;
    $(".cat1 + .value").each(function(){
         sumCat1 += parseInt($(this).text());  
    })
    $(".cat2 + .value").each(function(){
         sumCat2 += parseInt($(this).text());  
    })
    
console.log(sumCat1)
console.log(sumCat2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
        <td class="value">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat2">cat2</td>
        <td class="value">356</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cat1">cat1</td>
        <td class="value">486</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach in JQuery...

```js
var obj = {};

$('tr').each(function() {
  $this = $(this)
  if ($this.length) {
    var cat = $(this).find("td").first().html();
    var val = $(this).find("td").last().html();

    if (cat) {
      if (!obj[cat]) {      
        obj[cat] = parseInt(val);
      } else {
        obj[cat] += parseInt(val);
      }
    }
  }
})

console.log(obj)
```